# MS Teams Graph API - How to Allow guests to speak in chat and not to send invitation to the organizer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'd like to create Teams online meetings using Graph API Create onlineMeeting in my application. I have configured the [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy) so that my application can create meetings without users.

I'd like to create the following meetings: **1)All participants can enter without lobby, 2)All participants can speak in chat, 3) The organizer doesn't get invitation**. But currently guests cannot speak in chat and an invitation will be sent to the organizer in the following request. How can I fix this?

Request

```
 {
   "subject":"test meeting",
   "lobbyBypassSettings": {"scope":"everyone"},
 }
```

Response

```
 {
     "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('39................')/onlineMeetings/$entity",
     "id": "MSo...............",
     "creationDateTime": "2021-11-24T04:48:07.7082659Z",
     "startDateTime": "2021-11-24T04:48:05.4391977Z",
     "endDateTime": "2021-11-24T05:48:05.4391977Z",
     "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/.................",
     "joinWebUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/....................",
     "meetingCode": null,
     "subject": "test meeting",
     "isBroadcast": false,
     "autoAdmittedUsers": "everyone",
     "outerMeetingAutoAdmittedUsers": null,
     "isEntryExitAnnounced": true,
     "allowedPresenters": "everyone",
     "allowMeetingChat": "enabled",
     "allowTeamworkReactions": true,
     "allowAttendeeToEnableMic": true,
     "allowAttendeeToEnableCamera": true,
     "recordAutomatically": false,
     "capabilities": [],
     "videoTeleconferenceId": null,
     "externalId": null,
     "broadcastSettings": null,
     "audioConferencing": null,
     "meetingInfo": null,
     "participants": {
         "organizer": {
             "upn": "...............@...........onmicrosoft.com",
             "role": "presenter",
             "identity": {
                 "acsUser": null,
                 "spoolUser": null,
                 "phone": null,
                 "guest": null,
                 "encrypted": null,
                 "onPremises": null,
                 "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                 "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                 "applicationInstance": null,
                 "application": null,
                 "device": null,
                 "user": {
                     "id": "39.................",
                     "displayName": null,
                     "tenantId": "3e.............................",
                     "identityProvider": "AAD"
                 }
             }
         },
         "attendees": [],
         "producers": [],
         "contributors": []
     },
     "lobbyBypassSettings": {
         "scope": "everyone",
         "isDialInBypassEnabled": false
     },
     "chatInfo": {
         "threadId": "19:meeting..............................",
         "messageId": "0",
         "replyChainMessageId": null
     },
     "joinInformation": {
         "content": "data:text/html,..........",
         "contentType": "html"
     }
 }
```

(Partially omitted.)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @ChetanSharma-msft . I'll wait for your message.

Comment: 1.You can automatically allow people in your organization bypass the lobby. Configure in Teams admin center > Meetings > Meeting policies > Participants & guests.(https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/change-participant-settings-for-a-teams-meeting-53261366-dbd5-45f9-aae9-a70e6354f88e)  2. Under Calling, Meeting, and Messaging, Chat – Turn this setting On to give guests the ability to use chat in Teams (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/set-up-guests#configure-guest-access-in-the-teams-admin-center)

Comment: Hi, @Prasad-MSFT .Thanks for the reply. I understand the ways for #1 and #2. What do you think about #3? I'm actually having the most trouble with #3.

Comment: I think, there is no such way to do this. I think the organizer will get notification by default.

Comment: Hi, @Prasad-MSFT . Thanks for the comment. Isn't it possible to not specify an organizer when a user create a Teams online meeting from My Applications?

Comment: Its not possible to not specify organizer.

Comment: Hi, @Prasad-MSFT . Thanks for the comment. I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For more visibility, adding the answer form the comment section:

1.You can automatically allow people in your organization bypass the lobby. Configure in Teams admin center > Meetings > Meeting policies > Participants & guests.([support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/…](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/change-participant-settings-for-a-teams-meeting-53261366-dbd5-45f9-aae9-a70e6354f88e))

2. Under Calling, Meeting, and Messaging, Chat – Turn this setting On to give guests the ability to use chat in Teams ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/set-up-guests#configure-guest-access-in-the-teams-admin-center))
3. There is no such way to do this. I think the organizer will get notification by default.